# How can I do a Continue option that starts the script again?

Tags: shell-script

I have a script with case, functions and if statements.
Then I want to create an option that when the user press the enter button it starts the script right at the top.

This what I have done:

```
read -p "Enter to continue" enter

key=$(~/folder/script)

if [[ $enter = "" ]]; then

          $key
else

         echo "Wrong key!"
fi
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like a homework assignment... here's a tip for you: you'll probably want to create a loop. It can be an infinite loop with a specific command to break out of it if the user chooses an "exit" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash assumed, simply: `exec $0`.

- `$0` evaluates to the full script path.
- `exec` will launch the script, replacing the current instance with a new one.

When placed after `echo "Wrong key!"`, `exec $0` will restart the script, which will prompt for new input.

For `exec` reference, see bash documentation:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec